# angular - How to dynamically change the content in the index.html file when running the ng-build command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to change the URL of a script tag when I'm running the **ng build** command **with the --prod** option and **without the --prod** option. Following is an example.

**ng build --prod**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://my-site.net/prod.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ng build**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://my-site.net/dev.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like this isn't inherently provided in angular-cli, you could have a post build script as in this thread. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7824

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For current versions of Angular from v6.1.0-beta.2 on, you can use the `fileReplacements` value in the `angular.json` file configurations as detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274333/228429 by @massic80.

More info here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-395651237

For older versions before v6.1.0-beta.2, Angular CLI does not provide any such feature. But you can use environment variables to inject proper scripts dynamically on run time.

Eg:

`main.ts`

```
import { env } from './environments/environment';

if (env.production) {
   const script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = https://my-site.net/prod.js
   document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
   const script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = https://my-site.net/dev.js
   document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Read more here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-285329985

Comment: fileReplacement didnt replace index file, why?

Comment: fileReplacements of index.html doesn't work for me either on angular8 (I think there's now an "index":"src/index.prod.html" attribute, but that ones doesn't work either for me)

Comment: Using the dynamic approach in main.ts can be useful for things like changing a google analytics id per environment with configuration transformations as part of a deployment process, instead of during build.

Answer (score 12):

In `angular.json` you can configure the index file to be used (I'm using Angular 8):

```
"projects": {
    "projectName": {
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "options": {
                    "index": "src/index.html", // this is the default location (also for ng serve)
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "index": "index-prod.html" // this is the prod version (you can also link it to /prod/index.html or whatever: it will be placed in the dist root folder with the provided name)
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "index": "index-whatever.html" // this is the version for ng build --configuration=development`
                        }
                    }
                }
            }/*, UPDATED: THIS DOESN'T WORK
            "serve": {
                "index": "dev/index.html" // file to be used in ng serve
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

AFAIK none of those `"index"`s is mandatory, except the first

Sidenote: this is what I just tried with some tries, builds and `ng serve`s. I didn't find it in any documentation.

Check it out and let me know.

===========

UPDATE 19 Oct '19:
I noticed that the configuration reported above still uses `src/index.html` also for `serve` on `"@angular/cli": "^8.3.6", "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.8"`. Looks like there is no override for `serve` itself.
My question is: **should `serve` always inherit base `index` configuration?**

Trying to dig a bit more I found this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599

There is an example of how it should work with the new CLI, but attempting to replace the

```
"development": {
    index": "index-whatever.html"
}
```

with a

```
"development": {
    index": {
        "input": "index-whatever.html"
    }
}
```

and building, it gives me a
`Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".index" should be string.`

===========

UPDATE 10 Apr '20:

I just noticed that in October's update I missed a quote in the latest code snippet. I don't remember whether it was copied directly from my code - hence the reported error could be related to that - or it was a mistype when I attempted to rewrite the code. I'll check again whenever I'll have time

Comment: This answer is correct but could largely be simplified. Could you modify it and just give the final solution described [in this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237)? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50791541/719276) as an example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, but as I wrote the solution in the issue doesn't work on my side.

Comment: Although I am currently on 8.1.1 cli (end thus your first version worked), I have seen a solution here for later versions (not sure which one): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237. The scheme thing seems to be fixed by this PR: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/15582 but I am also not sure in which version this is released.

Comment: @massic80 ok sorry, I didn't realize that current solution does not work with previous angular versions or other settings.

Comment: You're welcome :) Actually, mine WASN'T a previous version, but validator didn't allow angular to compile it.
Is it working on your side? Interesting...

Comment: D'oh! I just noticed that in my latest code snippet I missed a quote. I don't remember whether it was copied directly from my code - hence the error could be related to that - or it was a mistype when I attempted to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to stick with standard `src/index.html` while serving locally by want to have specialised `index.html` files per production / test configuration (as it was in my case, where different Google Analytics code chunks have been to be applied) do it simply:

1. Create separate directories each holding a dedicated version of `index.html`.
   Eg.:

`src/prod/index.html`
`src/test/index.html`

2. Let `angular.json` know about them, per configuration:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        ],
        "index": "src/index/prod/index.html",
        // other stuff
    },
    "test": { 
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }
        ],
        "index": "src/index/test/index.html",
        // other stuff
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this aint pretty but it works, i just have 2 index files and i copy over the main one before the build

```
"build:en": "copy src\\index.en.html src\\index.html && ng build --configuration=production-en",
"build:fr": "copy src\\index.fr.html src\\index.html && ng build --configuration=production-fr",
```

Comment: take care that this method is not cross-OS

Answer (score 2):

With Angular 8 and 9 you can add custom webpack builder:
https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack

```
npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack
```

and follow instructions from this page:
https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/custom-webpack/README.md