# Angular 6 - Serving different index files depending on the environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a local environment and a production environment. Within the index.html i add or remove script files depending on if the environment is local or production.

I want an easy way to handle this. Inside the `angular.json` there is a file_replacement configuration option. This works for switching out the `environment.ts` to an `environment.prod.ts` but it does not seem to work for replacing the `index.html` file to a `index.prod.html`.

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "demo": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts",
                                "output": "/assets/"
                            }
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles/style.scss",
                            "src/theme.scss",
                            "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
                            "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.min.js",
                            "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
                            "node_modules/ua-parser-js/dist/ua-parser.min.js",
                            "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
                            "node_modules/wordcloud/src/wordcloud2.js",
                            "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
                            "node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                },
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/index.html",
                                    "with": "src/index.prod.html"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "test": {
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "demo:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "demo:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
                            "node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.min.js",
                            "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
                            "node_modules/ua-parser-js/dist/ua-parser.min.js",
                            "node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
                            "node_modules/wordcloud/src/wordcloud2.js",
                            "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
                            "node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.min.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles/style.scss",
                            "src/theme.scss",
                            "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts",
                                "output": "/assets/"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "demo-e2e": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "demo:serve"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "demo",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "prefix": "app",
            "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "prefix": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is supported from version `@angular/cli@6.1.0-beta.2`.

---

**Update** (November 2019):

**[The `fileReplacements` solution does not work with
Angular CLI 8.0.0 anymore](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237)**

Change `angular.json` to set your production `index.html` instead:

```
"architect":{
  "build": {
    "options": {
     "index": "src/index.html", //non-prod
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production":{
      "index": { //prod index replacement
        "input": "src/index.prod.html",
        "output": "index.html"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the angular github reference where this change was implemented?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-395651237

Comment: yea, i am using it for over month now :)

Comment: It is not working for me. I am using Angular CLI: 6.1.1. File in `wwwroot/dist` is not `index.prod.html`, but `index.html`.

Comment: what version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` are you using?

Comment: Still works for me, i'm on `@angular/cli: 7.2.2` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.12.3`. Maybe open new question with your `angular.json` setup and `package.json` with versions you are using i can have a look.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [in this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599#issuecomment-527131237), change `angular.json` to set your production `index.html`:

```
"architect":{
  "build": {
    "options": {
     "index": "src/index.html", //non-prod
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production":{
      "index": { //prod index replacement
        "input": "src/index.prod.html",
        "output": "index.html
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Angular 8** "fileReplacements" did not work for replacing index.html. This was my solution.

**Current Working Solution**

```
...
"production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
...
```

***Full Build Configuration***

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/bandbutter-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./animate.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js"
              }
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular 8 and I don't know why it doesn't work on my side.
But I can specify the location for the `index.html` for any build configuration (and looks like also `serve`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57274333/3473303

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you need to update your angular.json file for production configuration

see image.