# how can i use different index.html files with ng serve and ng build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Because of the way we are set up here, my local development environment (ng serve) is not the same as my production build environment( ng build --base-href="/path/" --prod.  I'd like to use different index.html files for serve and build, with the build still generating the correct index.html.

If I change my angular.json, I get a message that property fileReplacements is not allowed.  File replacement for ng serve seems simplest to maintain though.

```
"serve": {
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me an error that the property fileReplacements is not allowed in the serve section.  Package.json has @angular/core ^8.0 and angular cli ~8.0.2.

Whenever I search for a solution, my results point me to the fileReplacements documentation, but that doesn't seem to work.  The file isn't getting replaced.  I know there are tons of other ways to do this, but I'd like to do it the approved angular.json way if possible.

Comment: They changed the way file replacements works in angular 8 - seems it was unintentional to allow you to replace your index.html like this. There seems to be a replacement flag you can pass --index. Maybe this will point you in the right direction https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14599

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this out yet.  It looks like the right answer as well, but slightly more complicated. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 - Serving different index files depending on the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506477/angular-6-serving-different-index-files-depending-on-the-environment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the different index file, we can use in doing that in single file, set a variable in different variables to assign a boolean value or other value and use ngIf for the content in the index file to switch for one to another. I have not done this code but it should work.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines.


    <ng-container *ngIf='window.location.href === "http://localhost:4200">
          <p>Stuff</p>
     </ng-container>   Forgot to add that if no one else replies, that's the answer. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Got swamped and forgot to come back and mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it using the --index flag for ng build, without using different folders by doing the following:

dev file

```
src/index-dev.html
```

production file

```
src/index.html
```

angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "www",
        "index": "src/index-dev.html",
     }
```

cmd :

```
ng build --prod --index=/src/index.html
```

For some reason --index only accepts index.html and no other filename in this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Finally got round to implementing this, thought i would post this incase anyone else runs into the same problem as this provides an alternative answer. Ended up opting to use the `--index` flag in angular.json config.

Only downside is that i had to specify the same name file, so `index.html` which meant a few extra folders to separate the files.

File Structure

```
index_files 
    > environment_1
        > index.html
    > environment_2
        > index.html
```

angular.json

```
"configurations": {
    "environment_1": {
        "index": "index_files/environment_1.index.html"
    },
   "environment_2": {
        "index": "index_files/environment_2.index.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i developed the [NPM package](http://[Index%20file%20replacer][1]) that will copy index file from src folder replace in dist folder

```
  "scripts":{ 
"build": "ng build && npm run-script copy-index-file",
"copy-index-file":"node node_modules/index-file-replacer/lib/ --index=index2.html"
 }
```

in this example index2.html is a file that will be copied to dist folder

now run this command  `npm run-script build` it will build project and copy the index file to dist folder

Answer (score 0):

For me this configuration works (put `prod index.html` into `src/deployment/prod` and leave `dev index.html` in `src/` - it will be replaced in `dist/` folder when you run `ng build --prod`):

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
],
"assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/web.config",
    {
        "input": "src/deployment/prod",   -- here is prod index.html file
        "output": "/",                    -- this point to dist/
        "glob": "index.html"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `angular.json` file,

add an alternative index page to the production configuration for example:

`"index": "src/index.php"` to `projects.ClientApp.architect.build.configurations.production`:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "ClientApp": {
            "projectType": "application",
          + "schematics": {...},
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/client-app",
                        "index": "src/index.html", // <-- Default Index File for 'ng serve'
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
                      + "assets": [...],
                      + "styles": [...],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": // <-- PRODUCTION
                          + "budgets": [...],
                          + "fileReplacements": [...],
                            "index": "src/index.php", // <-- Index File for PRODUCTION
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                          + "optimization": {...}
                        },
                      + "development": {...}
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
              + "serve": {...},
              + "extract-i18n": {...},
              + "test": {...},
              + "lint": {...}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you run the commands:

- `ng serve` (uses the **index.html** file. **Serves for development by default**)
- `ng build` (uses the **index.php** file. **Builds for production by default**)

To change the configuration for `ng serve` or `ng build`, add the configuration:

- `ng serve --configuration production` (Warning will show - ignore it, will serve the **index.php** file)
- `ng build --configuration development` (will build with the **index.html** file for development)