# Angular fileReplacements works only for ng serve, not for ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to use a different `index.html` for production environment.
So I've created a `index.prod.html` file and in the `angular.json` I am using `fileReplacements` configuration for the production environment.

```
"build": {
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/index.prod.html"
                }
              ],
              ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app (ng serve) everything is fine, both I run for dev or prod env it loads the respective index.html

The problem is with the build, it build the index.html also for prod env.

Comment: Littlebit offtopic but I hope you are not using this to set the baseHref attribute.,

Comment: No, I need it to load different script

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with Angular 8 and also wanted to replace index files. I still wonder why `ng serve` and `ng build` work different here but found another solution for this problem in the following question [how can i use different index.html files with ng serve and ng build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205242/how-can-i-use-different-index-html-files-with-ng-serve-and-ng-build).

I switched to use the `--index` parameter for the build. So I added the different `index.html` files to an extra folder and linked them in the `package.json` to the different builds like this

```
"build:test": "ng build --index /src/index-files/test/index.html"
"build:prod": "ng build --index /src/index-files/prod/index.html"
```

This way the normal `src/index.html` is replaced by the referenced `/src/index-files/{test|prod}/index.html` version.

Hint: this solution only works for `ng build` since there is no `--index` option for `ng serve`. But in my case this was no problem.